# Wrapping a subset of a data frame with nearest observations on either side of subset by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a very large data frame (about 1GB and 1 million rows) that has observations from 10am -4pm.
I would like to make some plots with geom_step which zoom in on 1:00:00-1:00:05pm exactly, so I figured that to save RAM and time it would be faster to subset the original data. (rather than plot everything and zoom in afterward). Plotting everything is not an option unfortunately.
Since I am working with geom_step, I need to wrap my subset with before and after values otherwise things do not plot correctly.

Here is an example data set which is actually much smaller than my data, but the principle is in there:

```
set.seed(2)
c1 <- sort( sample(round(runif(10,1,10)*10), 10 , replace = TRUE ) )
c2 <- sample(c("A", "C", "T"), 10, replace = TRUE)
c4 <- round(runif(10)*1000)
d1 <- c(5, 12, c1, 96, 97, 98, 100)
d2 <- c("B", "C", c2, "B", "T", "T", "A")
d3 <- c(300, 400, c4, 200, 300, 300, 100)
dcat2 <- c(sample(1:2, 14, replace = TRUE), 1,1)

mydat <- data.frame(time = d1, category = d2, category2 = dcat2 , inventory = d3)
print(mydat)
#      time category category2 inventory
#  1     5        B         2       300
#  2    12        C         1       400
#  3    27        C         1        10
#  4    52        C         1       165
#  5    59        T         2       810
#  6    62        A         2       869
#  7    62        C         2       514
#  8    73        C         1       627
#  9    85        A         2       844
#  10   95        C         2       285
#  11   95        T         1       667
#  12   95        A         1       150
#  13   96        B         2       200
#  14   97        T         2       300
#  15   98        T         1       300
#  16  100        A         1       100

require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=mydat, aes(x = time, y = inventory, group = category, col = category)) + 
     geom_step() +
     facet_grid(.~category2)
print(p)
q <- ggplot(data=mydat, aes(x = time, y = inventory, group = category, col = category)) + 
     geom_step() +
     facet_grid(.~category2) +
     coord_cartesian(xlim = c(80,98))
print(q)
```

This plot works but since my real data is so large it takes forever to plot. 
I would also like the step plot to be assumed to start at zero at time =0 and hold the last value it had until time=100, instead of just disappearing and appearing out of nowhere like it does in `p` and `q`

The following is more in line with what I am trying to do. It gives an error, so I will need to wrap the `mydat.zoom` data frame with most recent observations (before), and last observation from within `mydat.zoom` (after), for each interaction of category and category2

```
require(dplyr)

mydat.zoom <- filter(mydat, time >80, time < 98)
r <- ggplot(data=mydat.zoom, aes(x = time, y = inventory, group = category, col = category)) + 
     geom_step() +
     facet_grid(.~category2)
```

`print(r)` gives an error,
because `geom_step` requires at least 2 points when graphing in facets, but some of these have been cut off by the subsetting to between time 80 and 98.

Please suggest an efficient way of finding, for each factor, the last observation before the zoom window and a way to copy the last observation and wrapping the zoom window in these (or a different solution!)

Comment: "c3" appears to be missing.

Comment: i ended up solving this problem since then, but haven't had time to revisit my question to add the solution. I used the data.table package (could have used the dplyr also) but the solution below is effective to solve the problem.

     require(data.table)

     mydat.zoom <- rbind( mydat[  time < 80, .SD[.N] , by = .(category1, category2)],
                                        mydat[ time >= 80 & time hi, 98 ],
                                        mydat[ time > 98, .SD[1] , by = .(category1, category2)])

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method that I used to bring past observations forward into the time window being examined:

```
require(data.table)
myDT <- as.data.table(mydat)
preDT <- myDT[ time < 80, .SD[.N] , by = .(category, category2)] # for each category/category2 interaction before time =80, take the last observation
mydat.zoom <- rbind(preDT, myDT[ time >= 80 & time <= 98] ) # gives everything from time = 80 to time =98 and the last observation for each thing that happened before time = 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a hack but it may help you get past this issue for now (i.e. until someone provides a cleaner solution).

This creates a temporary variable containing the occurrence count of each factor.  The result is then filtered to ensure at least 2 data points.

```
mydat.zoom <-
    filter(mydat, time >80, time < 98) %>%  # Your current filtering
    group_by(category2)                %>%  # Using cat2 for this example
    mutate(cat2_cnt = n())             %>%  # count to be filtered on
    filter(cat2_cnt > 1)               %>%  # Ensure >= 2 data points
    ungroup                            %>%  # Don't need grouping.
    select(-fcnt)                           # Don't need column anymore
```

Something like this may work for you.

**EDIT:**

A better solution using `dplyr` than the one above with the temporary variable.

```
mydat.zoom <-
    filter(mydat, time >80, time < 98) %>%  # Your current filtering
    group_by(category2)                %>%  # Using cat2 for this example
    filter(n() > 1)                    %>%  # Ensure >= 2 data points
    ungroup                                 # Don't need grouping.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I had wanted to include observations that only occurred once in that period as well though. I did solve the problem that I had since I posted it, and I included it in another comment for anyone who searches for the same issue